# How to read an array of numeric values from snowflake with JDBC?

Tags: java, arrays, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column with type ARRAY in a snowflake table containing float values.

I want to retrieve this column and create a `double[]` in Java with the JDBC connector.

This code

```java
int ARRAY_INDEX = 0;
resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnTypeName(ARRAY_INDEX);
```

returns `ARRAY` but when I try to read the data with

```java
resultSet.getArray(ARRAY_INDEX);
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeLoggedFeatureNotSupportedException
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeBaseResultSet.getArray(SnowflakeBaseResultSet.java:795)
```

All I have managed to read is a String:

```java
resultSet.getString(ARRAY_INDEX);
> "[\n -4.5,\n 2.8,\n 100.0, ... ]"
```

I could then split this string and parse it into doubles but this seems very inefficient.

Is there a way to directly retrieve an array of numeric values, ideally directly a double[] ?

Answer (score 0):

In the source for the Snowflake JDBC driver you can see that the method getColumnTypeName is not supported:

> https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/net/snowflake/client/jdbc/SnowflakeBaseResultSet.java

In fact, the implementations for all methods that return Array type return not implemented exceptions.

The Snowflake DB returns arrays the way you're seeing the string:

```
select array_construct(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) as MY_ARRAY;
```

Returns:

```
[
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5
]
```

So one way or another, Java code on the client is going to have to parse it. You could override the JDBC driver's `getArray` method to implement it instead of returning an error, but that's probably not worth it unless you have a lot of preexisting code using `getArray`. If you don't have existing code calling that method, you can just parse it in the class that's reading from the ResultSet.